# Have Zeilinger's hot $\rm C_{70}$ buckyballs classical properties?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interference, double-slit-experiment

Zeilinger showed experimentally that increasing temperature of $\rm C_{70}$ buckyballs causes the interference pattern in the double slit experiment to smear out increasingly.In other words the interaction of the photons radiated away with the environment causes decoherence of the quantum system, see https://www.oeaw.ac.at/fileadmin/Institute/IQOQI-Vienna/PDF/publications-zeilinger/2002_-_Quantum_Unspeakables_-_Interferometry_with_Macromolecules_Quantum_Paradigms_Tested_in_the_Mesoscopic_World.pdf

Question: supposed full decoherence, does a hot buckyball follow a definite path or more general does it behave like a classical particle before it hits the screen?

Question: Could one distinguish two cases experimentally:

1. a cold buckball still in a coherent state hits the screen.
2. a hot buckyball which already has lost its coherent state hits the screen.

And can case 2. be called a measurement at all? It is assumed that during a quantum measurement full decoherence of the system occurs. So what if a "measured" particle which has a decoherent history already arrives at the detector?

Comment: Does repeated weak measurement cause a quantum mechanical system to behave more classically? Yes. Heisenberg pointed this out first around 1927 or so in a paper that made a handwaving argument about Rydberg atoms if I remember correctly and Mott made a derivation of alpha particle tracks from wave mechanics in 1929. This is very, very old physics.

Comment: Wouldn't this consequently mean that the hot buckeyball being a classical particle with a definit path just sticks at the screen without a measurement process having taken place?

Comment: A "classical particle" is an approximation. The only question is how we get that approximation out of the theory. The correct answer is "be repeating many weak measurements". That answer has been known for a long time (close to a century, as you can see), it's just not being taught correctly in many QM 101 courses and there are still some researchers who can't believe that they are wasting their time on rather old knowledge. At least that's my opinion about this kind of research. I don't think it produces anything new or even borderline surprising.